# C++: trouble storing data in last element of int array

Tags: c++, arrays

The below code reads in a file and then counts the number of 'a', 'b', etc... characters, it counts both 'A' and 'a' as the same letter.

The code below works; however if I change the declaration of the int array count[26] = {0} to count[25] = {0} (and ONLY change this), the program will not properly store the number of 'z' characters, which is stored in the 25th element of the array. It will store -1 in the 25th element. I don't understand why? I never access count[26], only count[0] through count[25], but why must I add one more element to the array for the code to work? When count is 26 elements long the correct number of 'z' characters is stored in count[25].

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[], char **env)
{
// Declare variables

int c, big ;
int count[26] = {0} ;
int bar[25] = {0} ;
ifstream infile("histo.data") ;

while (!infile.eof())
{

        c = infile.get() ;
        c = tolower(c) ;

      if ( c >= 97 && c <= 122)
      {
         count[c - 'a']++ ;
      }

}
infile.close() ;

for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
{
    printf("%c: %d\n",(97+i),count[i]) ;
}


// find largest letter count
big = count[0] ;

for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++)
{

    if(count[i] > big)
    {
      big = count[i] ;
    }
}

// bar lengths
int cols  = atoi(getenv("COLUMNS")) ;
for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
    {
        bar[i] = (cols-3)*count[i]/big ;
    }

// print bars

for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
{
    printf("\n%c: ",(97+i));
    for (int j = 1; j <= bar[i]; j++)
    {
        cout << "=" ;
    }
}

cout << "\n" << endl ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are zero indexed, however the number you declare them with is the *size* of the array. Therefore, if you want 26 items, you need to declare an array of 26. The index range is 0...25 though.

Answer (score 1):

`count[25]` declares an array of size 25, NOT an array where the last index is 25.  Because arrays are zero-indexed, the last legal index in an array is one less than the length.  There are 26 letters so you need an array of length 26, declared `count[26]`.